# How to make CSS using settings.value in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I set a value in settings_data.json of Shopify Config.

And I am trying to insert it into my CSS.

```
settings_schema.json
...
{
  "type": "image",
  "id": "image1.png"
  "label": "Background Image"
}
...
index.liquid
...
<style>
.div {
 background-color: url({{image1.png}});
}
</style>
```

But I can't get the background image.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a filter for the image in order to show the full URL address:

For example: `{{ image1.png | img_url: 'medium' }}`

Answer (score 0):

To get a value of the store settings you need to call the settings object. Also in your schema it seems that the id contains the value and a comma is missing. Double check this.

```
settings_schema.json
...
{
  "type": "image",
  "id": "image1", // Name of variable
  "label": "Background Image",
  "default": "image1.png" // Content
}
...
index.liquid
...
<style>
.div {
 background-color: url({{ settings.image1 }});
}
</style>
```